# Do Zarya's barriers protect against knockback effects?

Tags: overwatch

The few times I've faced Zarya in Quick Play, I noticed one or two times that Lucio's sound blast didn't seem to push her back while she had her barrier on, but given how finicky pushback is in Overwatch, I'm not sure if that was because of the barrier of because of general wonkiness.

Do Zarya's barriers stop the knockback effects of Lucio's sound blast, Pharah's Concussive Blast, and so on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [WIKI] it does protect against all stuns and knockbacks.[1](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Zarya):

> Particle Barrier: When activated, Zarya will completely surround
>   herself with a barrier for a brief period of time, absorbing a large
>   amount of damage and making her immune to all negative effects (such
>   as knockback or stun) while the barrier holds. Damage dealt to the
>   Particle Barrier contributes to her Energy.

Comment: In addition, it protects against the slowing effects applied by Mei's weapon/ultimate and Symmetra's turrets. Handy!

Answer (score -1):

Zarya's barriers not only protect from damage, but also from all their side effects, including pushback, Venom Mine's poison, Mei's slow/freeze and I believe Junkrat's trap.

Comment: New answers should make a meaningful and significant contribution not found in existing answers. You've named a couple specific abilities that might be covered by "all negative effects", but that seems to be it. This should probably have been a comment on the existing answer.